# Insert an array into another in a particular position without removing existing elements

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, insert

I'm doing an exercise of `POO` but with pointers, and I have to insert an array into another in the position that is requested, without overwriting or losing those that are, just move it.

In the function `void IntArr::addElement(int pos,int qtty,int *vec)` I do exactly that, but as you will see, I complicate my life to do it.

Is not there a more efficient way to do this to avoid so many lines of code?

Some references:

`qtty` is the number of elements that I want to pass from the vector to insert.

`pos` is the position I want to insert.

`vec` is the vector to insert

`p` dynamic vector where I'm going to insert values

`used` quantity of used elements of vector p

`size` Vector size p

I leave the code of the functions, but if you need the full class and the main to understand what I need, tell me and I edit it.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "IntArr.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#define PRESS_KEY std::cout<<"\nPresione Enter para continuar . . .\n";std::cin.get();
#define SZ_VEC(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

class IntArr
{
  private:
    int * p;
    int size;
    int used;

    //Verificador
    void redimensionador(int cant);
    void verificarPos(int &pos);

  public:
    //builders
    IntArr (int sz);
    IntArr (int sz,int qtty,int *vec);

    //Destroyer
    ~IntArr();

    //Print
    void prtArr (void) const;

    //Gets
    int getSize(){return size;};
    int getUsed(){return used;};

    //Adds
    void addElement(int pos,int xx);
    void addElement(int pos,int qtty,int *vec);
};

//Builders
IntArr::IntArr(int sz){
  size = sz;
  used = 0;
  p = new int[size];
}

IntArr::IntArr(int sz,int qtty,int* vec){
  if(qtty>sz){
    sz = qtty;
  }
  size = sz;
  used = qtty;
  p = new int[size];
  for(int i=0;i<used;i++){
    p[i] = vec[i];
  }
}

//Destroyer
IntArr::~IntArr(){
  delete []p;
}

//Print
void IntArr::prtArr(void) const{
  if(used == 0){
    cout<<endl<<"El array no tiene elementos."<<endl;
  }
  else{
    cout<<endl<<"Array: ";
    for(int i=0;i<used;i++){
      cout<<p[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }
}

//Add value 'xx' in position 'pos'
void IntArr::addElement(int pos,int xx){
  verificarPos(pos);
  redimensionador(1);
  for(int i=used;i>pos;i--){
    p[i] = p[i-1];
  }
  p[pos] = xx;
  used++;
}

//Add Vector in position 'pos'
void IntArr::addElement(int pos,int qtty,int *vec){
  verificarPos(pos);
  redimensionador(qtty);

  // Iterator of auxiliary vectors
  int j=0;

  // We see the amount of elements to move
  int cantDesp;
  cantDesp = used - pos;

  // We create the auxiliary vector with the amount of elements to be moved
  int vAux[cantDesp];

  // Go through the original array to save the elements to be moved
  for(int i=pos;i<used;i++){
    vAux[j] = p[i];
    j++;
  }

  // We see where the new items arrive to add
  int espNew;
  espNew = pos + qtty;
  j=0; // Restart iterator

  // We add the new items to the vector p[]
  for(int i=pos;i<espNew;i++){
    p[i] = vec[j];
    j++;
  }

  // We calculate the pos up to where the displaced items will go
  int pAux;
  pAux = used + qtty;
  j=0; 

  // We use the vAux to add saved items
  for(int i=used-1;i<pAux;i++){
    p[i] = vAux[j];
    j++;
  }
  used += qtty;
}

//Resize
void IntArr::redimensionador(int cant){
  if(cant+used>size){
    if(cant > 5){
      size += cant;
    }
    else{
      size += 5 + cant;
    }
    int *temp = new int [size];
    memcpy (temp,p,used*sizeof(int));
    delete [] p;
    p = temp;
  }
}

//Checker of position
void IntArr::verificarPos(int &pos){
  if(pos<=0){   // If the position is negative or equal to zero
    pos = 0;
   }
  else if(pos>=size){ // If the position exceeds the size of the array
    pos = used;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int v1[]={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40};
  int v2[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
  IntArr A(10,SZ_VEC(v1),v1);
  cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
  A.prtArr();
  A.addElement(0,77);
  A.addElement(56,11);
  A.addElement(4,SZ_VEC(v2),v2);
  cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
  A.prtArr();
  A.addElement(4,99);
  cout<<" size:"<<A.getSize()<<endl<<" used:"<<A.getUsed()<<endl;
  A.prtArr();
  PRESS_KEY;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a standard container such as `std::vector`, `std::list`?  They have operations for insertion of elements, that take care of moving elements and resizing, and - if the container type supports it - tend to be optimised.

Comment: @Peter This is clearly a pedagogic exercise to learn how to implement containers.

Comment: What is `POO` in this context?

Comment: @Peter I have not been shown these containers yet, but thanks for your suggestion. I will investigate about it.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic It is an IntArr class in which we implement certain methods to exercise `POO` with pointers

Comment: What is POO? Fortunately, that is not a common acronym. Exactly what are the hobbles that the teacher has imposed?

Comment: @JiveDadson Sorry, `POO` is `OOP` in Spanish. I think you knew. My teacher gave us a practical work to practice about OOP with pointers, many functions with respect to pointers not know them as much as my colleagues. So we are looking at Google and serious forums, like this one, for more experienced people to help us improve our code to something more readable.

Comment: @JiveDadson already edit my code in case you want to see it again

Comment: @Calvin You can learn OOP without having to deal with the intricacies of trying to write a container class.  How are Java students able to learn OOP without dealing with pointers?  In addition, writing a proper container class is much more than just "how to use pointers".  Your `IntArr` by itself is not complete in that `{ IntArray a(1); IntArray b = a; }` will fail miserably on you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I know, but this is for practice. We already learned the basics of OOP with C++, in fact next week I have the exam, this is for a practical paper I have to deliver.

Comment: Next time I encounter an OO zealot, I'll have to mention `OOP` is expressed in Spanish as `POO`.   :-)